# ¿Es posible establecer el orden en una sentencia de UPDATE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

Digamos que tengo una tabla como la siguiente:

```
LineId  Linea
------- -----------
1       Linea 1
2       Linea 2
3       Linea 3
4       Linea 4
```

---

Y busco obtener una salida como esta:

```
LineId  Linea
------- -----------
1   Linea 1, 
2   Linea 1, Linea 2, 
3   Linea 1, Linea 2, Linea 3, 
4   Linea 1, Linea 2, Linea 3, Linea 4,
```

---

Creo que la idea se entiende, concatenar de manera acumulativa cada línea, y en el orden dado por `LineId` (fundamental). Una forma bien rústica de resolverlo sería hacer algo así:

```
DECLARE  @Temporal VARCHAR(8000)
UPDATE  #Ejemplo 
    SET @Temporal = ISNULL(@Temporal,'') + Linea + ', ',
        Linea = @Temporal
    FROM #Ejemplo
```

---

Pero, aquí es dónde me pregunto: ya que las tablas no tienen un orden natural y tampoco se puede configurar un `ORDER BY` en una sentencia de `UPDATE` o al menos no sé como hacerlo, la sentencia anterior, que en el ejemplo funciona bien, no me garantiza el orden de actualización. Podría bien estar generando algo como esto

```
LineId  Linea
------- -----------
1   Linea 1, 
2   Linea 1, Linea 3, Linea 2, 
3   Linea 1, Linea 3,
4   Linea 1, Linea 3, Linea 2, Linea 4,
```

---

Detalles adicionales:

- El ejemplo es una prueba de la idea del problema, funcionará bien, posiblemente siempre
- En la realidad, tengo un caso parecido, un código heredado, que procesan archivos secuenciales de texto
- De manera errática se detectan casos dónde no se mantendría el orden de inserción
- Tengo claro que no existe un "orden de inserción", no me quejo del comportamiento del SQL Server, es lo esperado. Lo que sí, este comportamiento, se empezó a verificar al cambiar una versión del motor (2008 a la siguiente)
- La solución que no me gusta, pero funciona, es la de usar cursores y actualizar por fila
- Me gustaría ver si hay alguna forma más elegante o natural de resolverlo
- Hasta ahora he intentado sin mucho éxito: a) Agregar a la tabla un identity que represente el orden, a ver si por defecto el motor lo utiliza b) Pasar por la generación de un XML, pero hasta ahora no logré el resultado esperado.

#### Para reproducir los datos

```
CREATE TABLE #Ejemplo (
    LineId  INT IDENTITY,
    Linea   VARCHAR(8000)
)

INSERT INTO #Ejemplo(Linea)
    VALUES  ('Linea 1'), ('Linea 2'), ('Linea 3'), ('Linea 4')
```

Comment: En Oracle existe la función listagg, quizá buscando por ese camino encuentres algo parecido en sql

Comment: Hola Patricio. [Esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3439110/5587982) y sus respuestas pueden ser de interés en este caso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existen varias opciones para hacer esto.

Mi primer sugerencia viene de uno de los profesionales de SQL Server que más respeto. Tiene un rendimiento excepcional y ha tenido una serie exhaustiva de pruebas para tratar de romper el código pero a la versión perfeccionada no se le han econtrado fallas. En inglés se le llaman "Quirky Update" y requiere seguir una serie de reglas para hacerlo de forma correcta. Todo está explicado en [este artículo](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/solving-the-running-total-and-ordinal-rank-problems-rewritten) pero dejo un resumen de lo que hay que hacer.

1. **Tener un índice clustered en el orden correcto**: Debe ser un índice clustered aunque no sea la llave primaria. Será el que dicte el orden.
2. **Se debe prevenir el paralelismo**: Es completamente necesario usar OPTION (MAXDOP 1) en el código para evitar que el paralelismo afecte el orden.
3. **No trabajar con tablas particionadas**: Si se debe trabajar con una tabla así, es mejor copiar los datos a una tabla temporal y trabajar sobre ella.
4. **Usar el hint TABLOCKX**: Es indispensable asegurarnos de que la tabla no será modificada durante el UPDATE. Con tablas temporales locales, no es necesario, pero sigue siendo sugerido.
5. **No usar JOINS**: Un JOIN puede alterar el orden de la tabla que tratamos de actualizar, por lo tanto es indispensable que no se usen en el UPDATE.
6. **Debe existir una columna "ancla"**: Lo ideal es que sea la primer columna del índice. Esta no necesita ser parte del cálculo.
7. **No usar ORDER BY**: ORDER BY no funciona con UPDATEs. Si no marca error, al menos será ignorado y se utilizará el índice clustered.
8. **No tratar de usar hints de índices para forzar el orden**: Solo se usará el índice clustered, así que no es necesario.
9. **Mantenlo correcto**: Es fácil equivocarse usando 3 partes del UPDATE, hay que asegurarnos de que todo esté correcto.
10. **¡HACER PRUEBAS!** Siempre es importante probar todos los escenarios posibles y con cantidades de datos relevantes para asegurar que el código funciona correctamente.

El código modificado termina así:

```
CREATE TABLE #Ejemplo (
    LineId  INT IDENTITY ,
    Linea   VARCHAR(8000)
);
--Indice Clustered
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX CI_Ejemplo ON #Ejemplo(LineId);

INSERT INTO #Ejemplo(Linea)
    VALUES  ('Linea 1'), ('Linea 2'), ('Linea 3'), ('Linea 4');

DECLARE  @Temporal VARCHAR(8000),
         @LineID int; --variable para columna ancla

UPDATE  #Ejemplo WITH (TABLOCKX) --Bloquear la tabla por completo
    SET @Temporal = Linea = ISNULL(@Temporal + ', ','') + Linea, --update de 3 partes
        @LineID   = LineID --columna ancla
    FROM #Ejemplo
    OPTION (MAXDOP 1); -- Prevenir el paralelismo

SELECT *
FROM #Ejemplo;
```

La otra opción que se me ocurre es actualizar por medio de una CTE. El problema es que terminas con un "JOIN triangular" que genera demasiadas filas y puede ser un problema tremendo y más lento que usando un cursor para actualizar fila por fila. Por cierto, un cursor estático que solo avance y que esté dentro de una sola transacción puede ser bastante eficiente también.

Esta es la segunda idea

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT *,
            STUFF(( SELECT ', ' + i.Linea
                FROM #Ejemplo i
                WHERE i.LineId <= e.LineId
                ORDER BY LineId
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('./text()[1]', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 2, '') Linea_Comp
    FROM #Ejemplo e
)
UPDATE CTE
SET Linea = Linea_Comp;
```